# Is it possible to elongate particles based on velocity?

Tags: particles

I would like to elongate particles along their direction of movement proportional to their velocity. Is this possible?

So instead of this:

[image]

I'd like to have something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe try playing around with softbodys?

Comment: planning to use it with regular particles too so a more general solution would be good.

Answer (score 2):

### Half of the solution (read below) with animation nodes

I got close to the solution using animation nodes. It might be very easy to work on this to make it a complete solution but, I must admit, it's my first time using AN!

[image]

I've used Animation Nodes [v2.0](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases).

The plane (*Plane*) emits a particle system with 3 particles with a starting normal velocity and default newtonian physics. Particles **must not be displayed via the particle system Render settings**. In fact, we'll do it using animation nodes. I've also created a "water drop" mesh (*Sphere*) for duplication.

This is my animation node setup:

[image]

It creates as many copies of *Sphere* as there are (alive) particles, then it scales them along their Z axis by an amount proportional to each one's *Velocity* vector length. Finally, it rotates the instances to match the direction of the velocity.

#### HOWEVER, I am not able to pass a list of rotations to the "Transform Output" node, so I'm only passing ONE rotation, namely that of the first particle!!

If anyone knows how to pass a list of rotations instead of a single rotation, feel free to add a new answer.

---

Blend file (requires animation nodes):

[image]